# Current political events

Tags: riddle, word

If you read aloud and listen,
right after this you can sense her.
Privacy is an issue, but not if you don't know.
Block, stop, and hinder,
take away my sights.

What am I, do you know?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure this is it, but is the word

> Censor

If you read aloud and listen,
right after this you can sense her.

> sense her sounds like censor

Privacy is an issue, but not if you don't know.
Block, stop, and hinder,
take away my sights.

> all seem to be referring to censorship.

And the title

> could also be related as censorship has been a political thing for quite a while

Comment: Nice job! It seemed more challenging when I was thinking about it, but the reasoning makes it seem easy. Hope you enjoyed either way!